# Can't see all photos on iPhone when connected to Win10

Tags: windows-10, backup, iphone, photos

Not wanting to use iCloud any longer for space and privacy reasons, I am trying to back up my iPhone photos to my Win10 PC via USB.  The phone is connected to the PC with a USB cable and when plugged in I trust the PC and allow access to storage on the phone.

I navigate to folders "This PC\Apple iPhone\Internal Storage\DCIM\100Apple and 101Apple" where I only see a few recent photos not all that are really there when I open the camera roll on the phone.  The Win10 Photos app can see the phone but it too only has access to the recent photos, not all of them.

One caveat I should mention is that I turned off iCloud storage for photos last month and they were to be deleted from the cloud in a couple of days.  As I can't back them up off line right now, I turned iCloud storage back on.

Does anyone have an idea where the photos are or why I can't seem them?

Comment: If you have them in iCloud, then that's where they are; your phone will migrate off anything except very recent - everything else will just be thumbnails. Were you not given the option of restoring them all to a local device when you switched off the iCloud storage?

Comment: Only the very recent photos is exactly what I saw on the phone when iCloud storage was off.  I don't recall a recent device being offered to download to when I turned off iCloud storage, perhaps I ignored it, however I was able to download the originals to the phone at that time.  I have them in iCloud again now.  When iCloud storage was turned off the photos were no where to be found on the phone, at least a not any place that is shared with Win10, but they were most definitely on the phone.

Comment: Why don't you download them from iCloud, then?

Comment: Thats what I did for now but will still need the back them up from the phone when I turn the cloud off and cant find their location on the phone.